# Moving from IntelliJ to Visual Studio - Deep SVN integration features hidden, or available via plugin?

Tags: svn, version-control, visual-studio-2012, intellij-idea

I love Visual Studio but I miss some of the features IntelliJ has. Mostly, deep VCS integration.

IntelliJ color-codes file tabs based on VCS status - green for new, blue for modified, red for removed, etc. The VisualSVN plugin for VS comes close but doesn't have this feature as far as I can see.

Any other tips for moving from IntelliJ to VS welcome!

Comment: You can file a feature request colored tabs at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/feedback/?vsvn=

Answer (score 1):

The closest to IntelliJ you can come is to use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

ReSharper is made by [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) who also made IntelliJ.

At the moment it does not have any special [VCS support](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/303949) which is what you were asking for.

But you'll find many of the other goodies from IntelliJ in ReSharper:

- Refactoring tools
- XML support
- HTML/CSS/Javascript support
- The same keyboard shortcuts
- Unit test integration
- Plus much more...

Many Visual Studio developers cannot live without the ReSharper. I'm one of them.

Comment: I also can't live without ReSharper... After using it for one day! Thank you for the advice.